# History of Bash globbing

Tags: shell, regular-expression, wildcards, history

Is there a historical reason why Bash "globbing" and regular expressions are not identical? For example, I believe that in Bash `[1-2]*` matches anything that starts with a 1 or a 2 followed by anything else, while as a regular expression `[1-2]*` would match only a sequence of 1s and 2s. My Bash scripting and REGEX foo are both pretty weak and I regularly run into problems associated with these differences which made me curious was to why they are different.

Comment: Would you consider doing `rm -- ^[^.].*\.txt$` instead of `rm -- *.txt`?

Comment: Much of your Q's are touched on in this thread from lwn: http://lwn.net/Articles/96687/

Comment: There are commands that operate on filenames and take regexp. For example find, `find . -regex ".*\.txt$" | xargs rm --`, or `rename` for renaming files (it is `sed` for filenames), beware some systems have a different `rename`.

Comment: @richard, my `^[^.].*\.txt$` was to take into account the ignoring of dot files. Note that the `-regex` is a GNU extensions, some shells like ksh93 or zsh can incorporate regexps in their globs (try for instance: `ksh93 -c 'echo ~(E:^[^.].*\.txt$)'`)

Comment: There's not much that `bash` did invent. `bash` mostly cherry-picked features from different shells (Bourne, ksh, csh, tcsh, zsh). Globbing predates even the Bourne shell and used to be done with a `glob` command (only `?` and `*` were supported then) in the first versions of Unix in the early 70s.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the correction. Makes one realise how much simpler globbing is, though less powerful. May be that is why they are different, regex is just to difficult for every day use, and for beginners and sometimes for me. (I will remove my original comment, so it does no harm.)

Comment: That bash follows existing practice so carefully while avoiding irreconcilably incompatible changes and extensions is one of its greatest strengths.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`bash` was initially designed in the late 80s as a partial clone of `ksh` with some interactive features from csh/tcsh.

The origins of globbing have to be found in those earlier shells which it builds upon.

`ksh` itself is an extension of the Bourne shell. The Bourne shell itself (first released in 1979 in Unix V7) was a clean implementation from scratch, but it did not depart completely from the Thompson shell (the shell of V1 -> V6) and incorporated features from the Mashey shell.

In particular, command arguments were still separated by blanks, `|` was now the new pipe operator but `^` was still supported as an alternative (and also explains why you do `[!a-z]` and not `[^a-z]`), `$1` was still the first argument to a script and backslash was still the escape character. So many of the regexp operators (`^\|$`) have a special meaning of their own in the shell.

The Thompson shell relied on an external utility for globbing. When `sh` found unquoted `*`, `[` or `?`s in the command, it would run the command through `glob`.

```
rm *.txt
```

would end up running glob as:

```
["glob", "rm", "*.txt"]
```

and glob would end up running `rm` with the list of files matching that pattern.

```
grep a.\*b *.txt
```

would run `glob` as:

```
["glob", "grep", "a.\252b", "*.txt"]
```

The `*` above has been quoted by setting the 8th bit on that character, preventing `glob` from treating it as a wildcard. `glob` would then remove that bit before calling `grep`.

To do the equivalent with regexps, that would have been:

```
regexp rm '\.txt$'
```

Or:

```
regexp rm '^[^.].*\.txt$'
```

to exclude dot-files.

The need to escape the operators as they double as shell special characters, the fact that `.`, common in filenames is a regexp operator makes it not very appropriate to match filenames and complicated for a beginner. In most cases, all you need is *wildcards* that can replace either one (`?`) or any number (`*`) of characters.

Now, different shells added different globbing operators. Nowadays, the ksh and zsh globs (and to some extent `bash -O extglob` which implements a subset of ksh globs) are functionally equivalent to regexps with a syntax that is less cumbersome to use with filenames and the current shell syntax. For instance, in `zsh` (with extendedglob extension), you can do:

```
echo a#.txt
```

if you want (unlikely) to match filenames that consist of sequences of `a` followed by `.txt`. Easier than `echo (^a*\.txt$)` (here using braces as a way to isolate the regex operators from the shell operators which could have been one way shells could deal with it).

```
echo (foo|bar|<1-20>).(#i)mpg
```

For mpg files (case insensitive) whose basename is foo, bar or a decimal number from 1 to 20...

`ksh93` now can also incorporate regexps (basic, extended, perl-like or "augmented") in its globs (though it's quite buggy) and even provides a tool to convert between glob and regexp (`printf %R`, `printf %P`):

```
echo ~(Ei:.*\.txt)
```

to match (non-hidden) txt files with **E**xtended regular expressions, case-**i**nsensitively.

Comment: Cool write-up! You actually can't use `~(opt:pat)` for any of the capitalized options. Maybe `print -r -- ~(Ei).*\.txt$`. Putting the pattern inside seems to only be useful to avoid having to toggle an option on then off for part of a pattern. Oddly you can mix-and-match multiple pattern languages within the same glob though. `~(Ki)*.~(E)txt$` is equivalent. (In the end everything just gets converted to regex and passed to libast's regex engine internally).

Comment: @ormaaj, `~(Ei:.*\.txt)` works for me even with 15 year old versions like ksh93 o+.

Comment: Works with one of my saved test binaries too (2014-12-24), but I recall running into issues with that. Things were always randomly broken and fixed again between each version back when ksh was still commercially developed. I remember the pattern matching code being one of the fragile areas.

Comment: @ormaaj, one different between `~(E)x` and `~(E:x)` is that the latter is _anchored_ (matches on `x` only while the former matches on  anything containing `x`), which may be the kind of issue you ran into (use `~(-lr)~(E:x)` to remove the anchoring, `~(E-lr:x)` won't do). In any case, I agree it's pretty  buggy, even in the latest version.

Answer (score 8):

[Regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) were introduced by [Kleene](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_memoranda/2008/RM704.pdf) in 1956. The seminal paper didn't have the full modern notation for regular expressions, but it did introduce the “Kleen star”: `A*` meaning “any number of repetitions of `A`”. In the next decade, some more or less standard notations emerged, in particular `.` for an arbitrary character and `?` to mean that the previous character is optional.

Bash's globbing notation stems from the [`glob` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29#Origin) introduced all the way back in [Unix v1](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/glob) in 1971. At the time, globbing was performed by a separate program; it was later moved into the shell. The early `glob` command has `?` to mean “any one character” and `*` to mean “any sequence of characters”. I don't know why the characters were chosen; `?` is pretty intuitive, and `*` may have been inspired from the one in regular expressions.

Globbing wasn't intended to be as general as regular expressions, and regular expressions were not very widespread at the time, so there was no call to unify the concepts. From the start, there were syntactic incompatibilities, with `?`, `.` and `*` meaning different things in file name patterns and in regular expressions.

Modern shells such as bash expand on glob patterns, but it was gradual evolution maintaining backward compatibility. Ksh88 (the 1988 version of the [Korn shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell)) introduced an extended syntax for shell patterns, which could not be the same syntax as usual regular expressions but was strongly inspired by it: `*(PATTERN)` to mean any number of repetitions of `PATTERN`, `@(PATTERN1|PATTERN2)` to mean “`PATTERN1` or `PATTERN2`”, etc.

Modern versions of bash (since 2.02) support ksh88's extended patterns, if you issue `shopt -s extglob` first.

Comment: Has Bash ever not supported extglobs? As far as I'm aware Bash, zsh, and {pd,m}ksh have supported the exact same globs as documented in the ksh88 manual since early days. Ksh to this day doesn't even have an option to disable "extended" glob quantifiers, and ksh93 is the only one of the bunch to have any extensions beyond what ksh88 had.

Comment: @ormaaj Ksh88 extended globs and the `extglob` option were introduced in bash 2.02 somewhere around 1998. Zsh acquired `ksh_glob` in the 3.1 series somewhere around the same time. Zsh has many globbing extensions of its own (some requiring the `extended_glob` option).

Comment: I see. So it actually was late enough to justify the need for an option. (I think the default being off is rather pointless these days but, interesting.)

Comment: @ormaaj, Note that in `bash`, contrary to `ksh`, extglob makes bash non-POSIX compliant because it's not disabled in variables. In `ksh`, `var='@(*)'; echo $var` expands to all the file names in the current dir that start with `@(` and end in `)` as POSIX requires while in `bash -O extglob` it expands to all the files. (still, one may consider bash behaviour makes more sense here (and the ksh behaviour is quite a pain when you do want to have patterns in variables)). That glob syntax is so awkward because of that (POSIX/Bourne compatibility). Compare with zsh extended globs.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's all true, and I like how ksh is somewhat smart about it. It rarely comes in to play though unless actually constrained to POSIX. With almost every use for wordsplitting replaced by better features, and storing patterns in variables being an extreme nuisance anyway since you have to empty IFS, disable brace expansion everywhere but bash. I think it's still impossible to be completely safe with stored patterns. This old [escape issue](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-04/msg00080.html) was never really resolved for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Historical reason: YES. Reference: 

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29#Origin)

Just to showcase the divergence, here is a good and easy example: `a*`

- shell globbing: meaning is, first character is `a` and then whatever (a, ab, abca...)
- regex: meaning is, zero or more repetitions of character `a` (a, aa, aaa...)

I'd readily agree that this discrepancy in meaning is very confusing for new users.

Globbing is perhaps easier to grasp for newcomers, but it also is less powerful construct.