# Why is nullglob not default?

Tags: shell, wildcards

In most shells `nullglob` isn't the default. That means, for example, if you run this command

```
ls *
```

in an empty directory, it will expand the `*` glob to a literal `*`, instead to an empty list of arguments. There are ways to change that behaviour, so that `*` in an empty directory will return an empty list of arguments, which would seem more intuitive.

So, is there a reason why `nullglob` is disabled by default? If so, what is that reason?

Comment: Somebody once made a bad choice that turned into "we've always done it this way". A very ubiquitous phenomenon (not only) in the software world.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda thought so, but is there like an origin point or anything like that? Was there any original reason, or was that purely arbitrary?

Comment: The original reason is that the nullglob option didn't exist back then. So to maintain backwards compatibility it must be disabled by default.

Comment: While it does not specifically mention the null glob, some history on globbing is provided by this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136409/22724

Comment: I get the impression some think it should be obvious that nullglob should be enabled by default. I don't think it's obvious. That expansions happen in the shell before command invocation means that expanding to nothing is a less intuitive behavior than the glob remaining unchanged.

Comment: @kojiro Less intuitive to whom? Anyone with any familiarity with \*NIX shells knows that `*` is a glob and expands to all *existing* files; how is it "intuitive" for there to be a special case where empty directory globs are "expanded" to a literal `*`?

Comment: @KyleStrand because it isn't expanded to a literal `*`. It's just _not expanded_.

Comment: @kojiro That's why I put "expanded" in quotes. The point is, when working with these shells, we come to expect that `*` will be expanded in a file-name context, unless it's escaped or appropriately quoted. The fact that this expansion doesn't occur in a specific context is a special case and therefore *not intuititive*.

Comment: @KyleStrand First, please understand that I'm not actually arguing whether or not nullglob is intuitive. I'm arguing that it's not _obvious_ that nullglob should be _on by default_. That is, it is not obvious that a historical default should be changed, especially in such a ubiquitous shell that (like it or not) has to track POSIX to some degree.

Comment: @kojiro You said (in your comment immediately before mine, to which I was responding): "...expanding to nothing is less intuitive behavior than the glob remaining unchanged." Hence my question: less intuitive to whom? I understand the historical argument, and the accepted answer (and my comment below it) have some good practical reasons for not having it on all the time. So I'm not arguing that you're wrong about whether or not the default should be changed; I'm just asking for clarification about your specific comment that the empty-expansion behavior would be "less intuitive".

Comment: @KyleStrand There's a bit to it, probably too much for the comments section. Chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42053/discussion-between-kojiro-and-kyle-strand).

Comment: why on earth would any one write `ls *` instead of `ls`?

Comment: @phuclv Because it is a very simple example of globbing. Could have used `cat` or any other tool as well, but this question was about globbig, not about `ls`. Also, in this very case, running `ls *` in an empty directory, actually results in a different result as `ls`. Or if you want to stick to `ls` and have a more realistic result, instead try `ls *.txt`.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The `nullglob` option¹ would not be ideal in a number of cases. And `ls` is a good example:

```
ls *.txt
```

Or its more correct equivalent:

```
ls -- *.txt
```

(to list files whose name ends in `.txt` except for those of type *directory* where it lists their contents instead; maybe you meant to use the `-d` option to avoid that special treatment of *directory* files).

With `nullglob` on would run `ls` with no argument which is treated as `ls -- .` (list the contents of the current directory) if no files match, which is probably worse than calling `ls` with a literal `*.txt` as argument².

You'd have similar problems with most text utilities:

```
grep foo *.txt
```

Would look for `foo` on stdin if there's no `txt` file.

A more sensible default, and the one of csh, tcsh, zsh or fish 2.3+ (and of early Unix shells) is to cancel the command altogether if the glob doesn't match.

`bash` (since version 3) has a `failglob` option for that (interesting to this discussion, since contrary to `ash`, AT&T  `ksh` or `zsh`, `bash` doesn't support local scopes for options³, that option when enabled globally does break a few things like the bash-completion functions).

Note that csh and tcsh are slightly different from `zsh`, `fish` or `bash -O failglob` in cases like:

```
ls -- *.txt *.html
```

Where you need all the globs to not-match for the command to be cancelled. For instance, if there's one txt file and no html file, that becomes:

```
ls -- file.txt
```

You can get that behaviour with `zsh` with `set -o cshnullglob` though a more sensible way to do it in `zsh` would be to use a glob like:

```
ls -- *.(txt|html)
```

In `zsh` and `ksh93`, you can also apply *nullglob* on a per-glob basis, which is a lot saner approach than modifying a global setting:

```
files=( *.txt(N)  ) # zsh
files=( ~(N)*.txt ) # ksh93
```

would create an empty array if there's no `txt` file instead of failing the command with an error (or making it an array with one `*.txt` literal argument with other shells).

Versions of `fish` prior to 2.3 would work like `bash -O nullglob` but give a warning when interactive when a glob has no match. Since 2.3, it works like `zsh` except for globs used in `for`, `set` or `count`.

Now, on the history note, the behaviour was actually *broken* by the Bourne shell. In prior versions of Unix, globbing was done via the `/etc/glob` helper and that helper behaved like `csh`: it would fail the command if none of the globs matched any file and remove the globs with no match otherwise.

So the situation we're in today is due to a bad decision made in the Bourne shell.

Note that the Bourne shell (and the C shell) came with another new Unix feature: the environment. That meant variable expansion (it's predecessor only had the `$1`, `$2`... positional parameters). The Bourne shell also introduced command substitution.

Another poor design decision of the Bourne shell was to perform globbing (and splitting) upon the expansion of variables and command substitution (possibly for backward compatibility with the Thompson shell where `echo $1` would still invoke `/etc/glob` if `$1` contained wildcards (it was more like pre-processor macro expansion there, as in the expanded value was parsed again as shell code)).

Failing globs that don't match would mean for instance that:

```
pattern='a.*b'
grep $pattern file
```

would fail the command (unless there are some `a.whateverb` files in the current directory). `csh` (which also performs globbing upon variable expansion) does fail the command in that case (and I'd argue it's better than leaving a dormant bug there, even if it's not as good as not doing globbing at all like in `rc`/ `zsh` / `fish`...).

---

<sup>¹ added in 2.0 in 1996 with the introduction of the `shopt` builtin, named after `zsh`'s equivalent option, though `bash` had the `allow_null_glob_expansion` *variable* for that in earlier versions</sup>

<sup>² for which `ls` would likely report an error that the `*.txt` file doesn't exist, unless it has been created in the interval, or the current directory happens to be searchable but not readable and that file or directory exists. Try after `mkdir -p '*.txt/wtf'; chmod a=,u=wx .` for instance</sup>

<sup>³ version 4.4 saw some improvement on that front in that options set by `set -o` could be made local to functions with `local -` like in the Almquist shell, but that doesn't work for `bash`'s second set of options, the ones set with `shopt`</sup>

Comment: There's another usability issue: `nullglob` appears to break tab-completion (pressing the tab key does nothing when it's enabled).

Comment: It's possible to use nullglob on a _per glob_ basis with bash - although the syntax is not as elegant as zsh `files=$(shopt -s nullglob;echo *.txt)`

Comment: @JonNalley, that stores the concatenation (with space) of the file names (with possible transformation with `xpg_echo`) into a _scalar_ variables. You'd need something like `readarray -td '' files < <(shopt -s nullglob; printf '%s\0' *.txt)` with `bash` 4.4 or above or `(shopt -s nullglob; printf '%s\0' *.txt) | xargs -r0 cmd` with GNU `xargs` for that to be usable at all with arbitrary file names. Or, still with bash4.4, use a helper function that uses `local -` (copied from ash 25 years later) for a local scope for options.

Comment: These [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) are very useful for precise definitions of what Bash does when expanding globs, including while nullglob and failglob are set/unset.

Comment: Nice analysis. May I ask in what case "no files match is worse than `ls` literal `*.txt`"? In the example `mkdir -p '*.txt/wtf'; chmod a=,u=wx .`. Do you mean if no `r` permission, `ls *.txt` cannot list `other.txt`? I think I understand this behaviour. But how is it related?

Comment: @midnite I do explain that `set -o nullglob; ls -- *.txt` lists the current working directory instead of txt files or `grep foo ./*.txt` greps stdin instead of txt files which is worse than letting ls/grep complain about those non-existent files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - Thank you! I get it now. But `set -o nullglob` does not work. `shopt -s nullglob` works. I do not know why my Bash `set` is missing `nullglob`.

Comment: @midnight, most shells set options with `set -o`. `set -o nullglob` works in zsh or yash for instance which both have that option. bash has two sets of options one that you set with `set -o`, the other that you set with `shopt -s`, and for that shell, nullglob is in the latter set indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This design incorporates a safe approach, considering the use of `nullglob` as the default for commands that yield void results when provided with void arguments. However, this default behavior may not be ideal for commands like `ls`. While `nullglob` proves useful in scripts, it is not entirely safe unless `ls` is replaced with a function, as demonstrated below:

```
myls() { (($#)) && ls "$@" ; }
```

This ensures the desired outcome when employing nullglob:

```
shopt -s nullglob
myls empty_directory/*
```

When designing a language default, the priority is to adopt an option that minimizes unexpected behavior. Opting for exceptions over unpredictable actions is preferred.

It's essential to note that introducing `nullglob` into a complex script with unpredictable input variations may render it unstable. In practice, it could be considered a seemingly good idea that, in reality, requires additional time for preventive debugging.