# How to print list filename using ls, but if not found retrun empty string?

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards

I have name file

- hua.txt
- hai.txt

if

```
print ls *{hua,las}* > taka.txt
```

in taka.txt return

```
ls hua.txt *las*
```

i want to `*las*` not there,

i just want in taka.txt

```
ls hua.txt
```

and filter `*{hua,las}*` must there... too

please help

Comment: For `bash` and `zsh` there is `shopt -s nullglob`, but see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204944) for an in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Many shells have different handles when a pathname expansion (glob) fails to match anything.

For example, in `bash` you have two shell options:

- `nullglob`:

  If a glob pattern fails to match anything, it is treated literally by default in `bash`. You can disable this behavior to return an empty string by setting the `nullglob` option beforehand:

  ```
  shopt -s nullglob
  ```
- `failglob`:

  This is more explicit, when a glob pattern fails to match anything `bash` shows a relevant error message:

  ```
  shopt -s failglob
  ```

Given your circumstances, you should go with `nullglob` if you are using `bash`, or look out for any similar option if you are using a different shell.