# A star is being printed for an empty directory after running a script to list the subfolder

Tags: shell-script

I was trying to write a shell script that will take a directory path d as an argument and recursively print a depth indented list of all files and directories in d. However, the argument d is optional and if no argument is given, a depth indented list of all files and directories​ ​in​ ​the​ ​current​ ​ directory​ will​ ​be printed.
Here is my code:

```
# the method for tree

myspace=""
spaceCount=0
tree(){     
  cd "$1"
  for i in *; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
      echo -n "|"   
      for (( j=0;j<spaceCount;j++ )) 
      do 
        echo -n "$myspace"  
      done
      echo "--$i"
      spaceCount=$((spaceCount+1)) 
      myspace="  |"
      tree "$i"
    else
      echo -n "|"
      for (( j=0;j<spaceCount;j++ )) 
      do 
        echo -n "$myspace"  
      done
      echo "--$i"
    fi
  done
  cd ../
  spaceCount=$((spaceCount-1))
}


if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
  file="$1"
fi
echo ".$file"
tree "$file"
```

But when a folder is empty, it's printing a star like this:[image]

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `bash` and Bourne-like shells in general (`zsh` being the exception), globs like `*` that match no file expand  to themselves (your script uses `ksh93` syntax, also recognised by `bash` and `zsh`, though in `zsh` you'd get fatal errors by default for non-matching globs).

`echo *` in a directory that contains no file (or only hidden files) outputs `*`.

Here instead of `for i in *`, use `for i in *(N)` (`zsh`) or `for i in ~(N)*` (`ksh93`) or if using `bash`, set the *nullglob* option (with `shopt -s nullglob`) so that the globs that don't match expand do nothing.

Alternatively, you could add a `[ -e "$i" ] || continue` at the start or your `for` loop to filter out the `*` by checking for file existence (would affect the behaviour for directories you have read but not search permissions to though¹).

More reading at [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)

---

<sup>¹ In those directories, `*` would expand to all the non-hidden files, but `[ -e "$i" ]` would return false for everyone of them as the `stat()` system call would return with *permission denied*</sup>

Comment: Where should I add `shopt -s nullglob`?

Comment: @sphoenix, before any command using a glob whose expansion you want to use the nullglob rule.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add a `[ -e "$i" ] || continue` at the start or your `for` loop to filter out the `*` by checking for file existence (would affect the behaviour for directories you have read but not search permissions to though). Could you kindly elaborate on "would affect the behaviour for directories you have read but not search permissions to though", please?

Comment: @sphoenix, see edit.