# `for in` command filename expension issue

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, for

I have a `bash` script with:-

```
for i in *.x *.y *.z *.a *.b *.c
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

If there are no files matching the pattern `*.y` then the variable `i` has the value `*.y`. When this happens, my logic get screwed up.

How do I stop that from occurring?

Comment: expansion or extension?

Answer (score 2):

That's where you want to use the `nullglob` option for non-matching globs to expand to nothing as opposed to being left asis

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *.x *.y *.z *.a *.b *.c; do
  ...
done
```

Here, you could also do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *.[xyzabc]; do
  ...
done
```

Which would be more efficient as there's only one glob to expand. Note however that the order would be different.

Or for extensions that are not single characters:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
for i in *.@(x|y|foo|bar); do
  ...
done
```

See [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803) for more on that and alternatives with other shells.